# How to load article page of a blog site using django?

Tags: python, django, web

I want to create a blog site. I already created the homepage of the site and there is 4 articles on my blog site. I want to open an article by clicking on it and it will redirect me to the unique article page. Every article page has few images and headlines and line breakers. How will I upload these to my blog model using django?
Example article page...[See the article page's picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3gtd.png)

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways to do this, but I would recommend CKEditor for Django

For the Blog home page and Detail pages, look at django's class based views:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.BlogListView.as_view(), name='blog_list'),
    path('detail/<int:pk>', views.BlogDetailView.as_view(), name='blog_detail'),
]
# You can also use <slug:slug> instead of <int:pk>
```

views.py:

```
from blog.models import Blog
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView

class BlogListView(ListView):
    model = Blog

class BlogDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Blog
```

For the blog formatting page:
https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor

https://medium.com/djangotube/django-ckeditor-install-with-youtube-and-code-spinet-plugins-b873c643f649

Change up your message/body to a RichTextUploadingField and then you/users can format images with text as you see fit.

models.py

```
from ckeditor_uploader.fields import RichTextUploadingField
class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    message = RichTextUploadingField()
```

In your settings follow the GitHub guide to setup CKEditor and you're also going to have to add MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT to your settings.py and project urls.py files.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

project/settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

project/urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```